# Alexa Trivia Skill - Quiz

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I was trying to make a Trivia Quiz. In general it is working fine, but the quiz doesn't recognize the answer and doesn't count the score correctly.
I don't know where to find the mistake in the code and how to change it.

I used this instruction and code for the quiz:
https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-trivia

I would be happy, if someone could help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO sir. Please provide minimal working example.

Answer (score 0):

For what you say, it may be both a problem of the Interaction Model and the Backend logic. Share the code, if you can :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code of the interaction model:

```
    {
"interactionModel": {
    "languageModel": {
        "invocationName": "teach me",
        "intents": [
            {
                "name": "AnswerIntent",
                "slots": [
                    {
                        "name": "Answer",
                        "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
                    }
                ],
                "samples": [
                    "die Antwort ist {Answer}",
                    "meine Antwort ist {Answer}",
                    "ist die Antwort {Answer}",
                    "{Answer} ist meine Antwort",
                    "{Answer}"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "DontKnowIntent",
                "slots": [],
                "samples": [
                    "weiß ich nicht",
                    "weiß nicht",
                    "überspringen",
                    "das weiß ich nicht",
                    "wer weiß",
                    "diese Frage weiß ich nicht",
                    "die weiß ich nicht",
                    "keine Ahnung"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.StartOverIntent",
                "samples": [
                    "Spiel starten",
                    "neues Spiel",
                    "starten",
                    "neues Spiel starten"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.RepeatIntent",
                "samples": [
                    "bitte wiederholen",
                    "noch einmal",
                    "wiederholen"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
                "samples": [
                    "Ich brauche Hilfe",
                    "Hilfe"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.YesIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.NoIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.NavigateHomeIntent",
                "samples": []
            }
        ],
        "types": []
    }
}
```

}

And I think the problem in the backend could be in the following part of the code:

```
   function isAnswerSlotValid(intent) {
      const answerSlotFilled = intent
        && intent.slots
        && intent.slots.Answer
        && intent.slots.Answer.value;
      const answerSlotIsInt = answerSlotFilled
        && !Number.isNaN(parseInt(intent.slots.Answer.value, 10));
      return answerSlotIsInt
        && parseInt(intent.slots.Answer.value, 10) < (ANSWER_COUNT + 1)
        && parseInt(intent.slots.Answer.value, 10) > 0;
   }

   function handleUserGuess(userGaveUp, handlerInput) {
      const { requestEnvelope, attributesManager, responseBuilder } = handlerInput;
      const { intent } = requestEnvelope.request;

      const answerSlotValid = isAnswerSlotValid(intent);

      let speechOutput = '';
      let speechOutputAnalysis = '';
      let aplFirstPageSpeechOutput = '';
      let aplSecondPageSpeechOutput = '';
      const sessionAttributes = attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
      const gameQuestions = sessionAttributes.questions;
      let correctAnswerIndex = parseInt(sessionAttributes.correctAnswerIndex, 10);
      let currentScore = parseInt(sessionAttributes.score, 10);
      let currentQuestionIndex = parseInt(sessionAttributes.currentQuestionIndex, 10);
      const { correctAnswerText } = sessionAttributes;
      const requestAttributes = attributesManager.getRequestAttributes();
      const translatedQuestions = requestAttributes.t('QUESTIONS');


      if (answerSlotValid
        && parseInt(intent.slots.Answer.value, 10) === 
        sessionAttributes.correctAnswerIndex) {
        currentScore += 1;
        speechOutputAnalysis = requestAttributes.t('ANSWER_CORRECT_MESSAGE');
      } else {
        if (!userGaveUp) {
          speechOutputAnalysis = requestAttributes.t('ANSWER_WRONG_MESSAGE');
        }

        speechOutputAnalysis += requestAttributes.t(
          'CORRECT_ANSWER_MESSAGE',
           correctAnswerIndex,
           correctAnswerText
        );
      }
```

If you need more code of the backend logic, let me know 
Thank you for your help :)